# Finding the inverse of a homeomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, geometry, normed-spaces

Let $f$ be the homeomorphism from $\overline{\mathbb{B}}^n$ to itself defined in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1474959) answer. I will use the same notation as the answer's author.

I wanted to know if it is possible to compute the inverse of $f$ as the author uses it to show the existence of the homeomorphism from one arbitrary point to another and not only $0$.
I tried to describe it geometrically using barycentric coordinates but at the end, for the $n=2$ case, I need to intersect a line (the one that goes through $f(x)$ and $v$) with $\mathbb{S}^1$ so it lead to ugly computations.
Here is a drawing that illustrate what I'm saying.
[image: geometric example of how the function works]

Also if it is not computable how can we show that this is a homeomorphism (do we need to use the equivalence between homeomorphism and openness) ?

Comment: It suffices to have a bijection which is continuous and compactness of $\Bbb D^2$ ensures it's a homeomorphism. There is no need to compute an inverse or even find a formula for it.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma using the close lemma, isn't it ?

Comment: Using that any continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is closed.